# show facebook like's count using page's name

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm new to Facebook API. How I can display Facebook's page '**likes**' using page's name?

For Example, Steptoinstall is the page's name (URL `https://www.facebook.com/steptoinstall`). If I give this name, can I know the likes count of this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This name is actually the unique **username** of the page. So, you can use this to make the call to the API `/{page-username}?fileds=like` and you'll get the response as:

```
{
  likes: 999999,
  id: "111222333"
}
```

Example:

> http://graph.facebook.com/Steptoinstall?fields=likes

Hope that helps!